# Why is a Spark Row object so big compared to equivalent structures?

Tags: apache-spark

I have been playing around with the `java-sizeof` library (https://github.com/phatak-dev/java-sizeof) and using it to measure data set sizes in Apache Spark. As it turns out, the `Row` object is ridiculously big. Like hugely big -- why is that?

Take a fairly simple schema:

```
root
 |-- account: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |-- dialed: string (nullable = true)
 |-- duration: double (nullable = true)
```

Example data looks like this:

```
+-------+-------------+----------+--------+
|account|         date|    dialed|duration|
+-------+-------------+----------+--------+
|   5497|1434620384003|9075112643|   790.0|
+-------+-------------+----------+--------+
```

So now we do:

```
val row = df.take(1)(0)
// row: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [5497,1434620384003,9075112643,790.0]
```

So now I use `SizeEstimator`

```
SizeEstimator.estimate(row)
// res19: Long = 85050896
```

81 megabytes! For a single row! Thinking this is some kind of mistake, I do:

```
SizeEstimator.estimate(df.take(100))
// res20: Long = 85072696
```

Interestingly, it's not much bigger -- only about 20k bigger, despite holding 100 times the amount of data. Above 100, it seems to get linear. For 1,000 rows it looks like this:

```
SizeEstimator.estimate(df.take(1000))
// res21: Long = 850711696
```

Ok, so that's about 10 times bigger than 100 rows -- more or less linear. And from tests, it increases in a linear fashion continuing past 100 rows. Based on these tests, after about 100 rows, **the cost per Row object is still over 800 KB** !!

Out of curiosity, I tried a couple of different object types for the same underlying data. For example, here are the results for an `Array` of `Array` objects instead of `Row` objects:

```
SizeEstimator.estimate(
  df.map(r => (r.getString(0), r.getLong(1), r.getString(2), r.getDouble(3))).take(1)
)
// res22: Long = 216
```

Ok, that's a little better. Even better, is that for 10 rows it is only 1976 bytes, and for 100 it is only 19,616 bytes. Definitely going in the right direction.

Then, I encoded the same `DataFrame` as an `RDD[Array[Byte]]` where each `Array[Byte]` is a binary-encoded `Avro` record, with the same schema as the underlying `DataFrame`. Then I do:

```
SizeEstimator.estimate(encodedRdd.take(1))
// res23: Long = 72
```

72 bytes -- even better! And, for 100 rows, it's 5,216 bytes -- about 52 bytes a row, and it keeps going down from there (48,656 bytes for 1,000 records).

So, at it's best, `Row` object weighs 850k per `Row`, whereas a binary `Avro` record of the same data is about 50 bytes.

What is going on??

Comment: This isn't what SizeEstimator is for. It's evaluating the number of bytes in the transitive object graph, which is pretty irrelevant to how much storage the Row object itself takes in memory or on disk. You're probably counting huge cache data structures in partition bookeeping, etc.

Comment: @SeanOwen There is something strange going on here and it seems to be all about `StructField`. [I've created a gist with minimal example](https://gist.github.com/zero323/0a8ef3636a6c4414d1bfcb9e6bfef94c) (no context, no `DataFrames`, single `StructField`) and it still gives an absurd number (271872172).

Comment: I don't think this method would ever give the number you are expecting. It is not trying to tell you amount of memory consumed by the Row object and just its data fields, somehow; it's telling you how big its entire transitive object graph is, almost all of which is not row data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually `Row` by itself is not that big. That is why you don't see a significant change in as size when you take more rows. Problem seems to be schema information:

1. When you collect data you actually get `GenericRowWithSchema`

   ```scala
   val df = Seq((1, "foo"), (2, "bar")).toDF
   df.first.getClass

   // res12: Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = 
   //   class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
   ```
2. [`GenericRowWithSchema` carries schema information](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d6dc12ef0146ae409834c78737c116050961f350/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/rows.scala#L207) from `schema` argument:

   ```scala
   class GenericRowWithSchema(values: Array[Any], 
     override val schema: StructType)
   ```
3. Lets confirm this is really the source of the problem:

   ```scala
   import com.madhukaraphatak.sizeof.SizeEstimator
   import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema

   val rowWithSchema = df.first 
   val rowWithoutSchema = new GenericRowWithSchema(
     rowWithSchema.toSeq.toArray, null)

   SizeEstimator.estimate(rowWithSchema)
   // Long = 1444255708

   SizeEstimator.estimate(rowWithoutSchema)
   // Long = 120
   ```
4. Hypothesis: Estimated size you see includes a size of the schema:

   ```scala
   SizeEstimator.estimate(df.schema)
   // Long = 1444361928
   ```

   which is roughly the same order of magnitude as collected rows. Lets create a new schema from scratch:

   ```scala
   import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

   val schema = StructType(Seq(
     StructField("_1",IntegerType,false), 
     StructField("_2",StringType,true)))


   val anotherRowWithSchema = new GenericRowWithSchema(
     Array(0, "foo"), schema) 

   SizeEstimator.estimate(anotherRowWithSchema)
   // Long = 1444905324
   ```

   So as you can see the results are consistent.
5. Why schema is so large? Hard to say.  When you take a look at the code you'll see that  [`StructType`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d6dc12ef0146ae409834c78737c116050961f350/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.scala#L94-L335) is a complex class even excluding its companion object not a simple schema definition.

   It doesn't explain reported size though. I suspect it could be some fluke in the `SizeEstimator` but I am not sure yet.
6. You can further isolate the problem but estimation a size of a single `StructField`:

   ```scala
   import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
   import com.madhukaraphatak.sizeof.SizeEstimator

   object App {
     def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val schema = StructField("foo", IntegerType, true)
       println(SizeEstimator.estimate(schema))
       // 271872172
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: But then why the linear increase past 100 rows?

Comment: Not to mention, holy crap 81MB is a lot for a schema. The `Avro` schema size is 3964 bytes -- even if we included the schema with every binary Avro record it would only be 4k per record, not 800k!

Comment: @DavidGriffin I am not sure yet. I don't even know if it a problem with `StructField` itself or `SizeEstimator`

Comment: Ok, I do believe you are onto something though about its relation to the `DataFrame.schema`, as `SizeEstimator` says my `DataFrame.schema` size is 85050504 bytes -- 300 bytes smaller than the individual `Row` object.

Comment: The million $$ question is, do I care -- does this really affect performance, and therefore one should take great care when using a `Row` object and doing things like collecting them into an Array?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't operate on Rows in the first place. There are not very elegant structure. But beyond this - beats me. I'll have to dig deeper but dragging all of that doesn't look like a good idea.

Comment: Fair enough. I do appreciate you looking at this though -- it was a shocking discovery, to say the least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109086/discussion-between-zero323-and-david-griffin).